# AWS Lambda returns 'null' after going through a forEach loop of saving multiple files in s3 bucket

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-sdk

I have an AWS Lambda function. It goes through a list of the array which is an array of URLs and saves their screenshot and puts them in s3. How do I return the output of this function which is screenshotLinks array that has all the links to files saved in s3? I used the callback function in the end, but it just returns null! I want callback function to output all the s3 file links saved inside screenshotLinks array.

```js
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {

desktopLinks.forEach(function (url, index) {
      https.request(url, function(res) {
        var data = new Stream();
        res.on('data', function(chunk) {
          // Agregates chunks
          data.push(chunk);

        });

        res.on('end', function() {
          var body = data.read();
          // Once you received all chunks, send to S3
          var currentLink = links[index];
          var linkAddress = encodeURIComponent(currentLink);
          var slashPosition = getPosition(currentLink, '/', 3)+1;
          var linkName = currentLink.substr(slashPosition, currentLink.length)
          var params = {
            Bucket: bucket,
            Key: completeDate + '/screenshots/' + linkName + '.png',
            Body: body
          };
          s3.putObject(params, function(err, data, callback) {
            if (err) {
              console.error(err, err.stack);
            } else {
              bunch = params.Bucket + '/' + params.Key;
              screenshotLinks.push(bunch);
            }
          });
        });
        
      }).end();
     
  })
  callback(null, screenshotLinks)
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is event driven / asynchronous which means you are calling the callback before screenshotLinks has been populated.

The node [http.ClientRequest.end()](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_request_end_data_encoding_callback) method finishes sending a request, but that doesn't mean that the response has been received and handled, as that is done by an asynchronous event handler. However, the callback is executed immediately after the call to request.end(), which is just after the request has been fired off, therefore screenshotLinks is empty.

You need to execute your callback from the callback you pass to s3.putObject. I suggest you pass your callback a response/result object that indicates whether the putObject succeeded and contains the url it relates to and either an error message or a screenshotLink, e.g. something like this:

```
      s3.putObject(params, function(err, data, callback) {
        var s3Response;
        s3Response.url = url;
        if (err) {
          s3Response.success = false;
          s3Response.error = err;
          console.error(err, err.stack);
        } else {
          bunch = params.Bucket + '/' + params.Key;
          s3Response.success = true;
          s3Response.screenshotLink = bunch;
        }
        callback(null, s3Response);
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

I would like to suggest you use an 8.10 node runtime.

ref: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/node-js-8-10-runtime-now-available-in-aws-lambda/

Then your entry point should be:

```
export async function <function_name>(event) {}
```

Then:

```
let s3 = new AWS.S3({ region: process.env.AWS_REGION, apiVersion: '2006-03-01' });
let params= 
{
     Bucket: /* a path to bucket (string) */,
     Key: name /* string */,
     Body: /* supported types (Buffer, Typed Array, Blob, String, ReadableStream) */,
     ACL: 'public-read',
     ContentType: 'image/png'
};

try
{
    let s3Response = await s3.upload(params).promise();
    // if succceed
    console.log(`File uploaded to S3 at ${s3Response.Bucket} bucket. File location: ${s3Response.Location}`);
}
catch (ex) // if error occured
{
    console.error(ex);
}
```